# How do I connect Excel securely to sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

My company wants to have approximately 100 of their sales people (distributed around the country) to be able to run stored procedures from excel and return the data onto the spreadsheet.

We have sql server 2008. i need to figure out a safe way to do this.

i will create a form in excel where the user can push a command button to refresh the data based on the parameters that they choose.

1. how can i ensure that the connection from excel to the sql server is secure?
2. how do i run a stored procedure from excel?

i found this to be very good information: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/connect-to-import-sql-server-data-HA010217956.aspx

> Windows Authentication    Select this option to use the Windows user
>   name and password of the current user. This is the most secure method,
>   but it can affect performance when many users are connected to the
>   server.

however, i would like your input on this.

yes, the sales reps do have windows logins, but can i use this solution if they will actually be entering specifying the data criteria, then sending the criteria over into the stored procedure and then getting the data from the server?

Comment: Can't you use an web interface or something? It's quite easy to execute a stored procedure and return a csv/xls. Doing this from excel just seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: @user606723 i totally agree with you but my boss wants to use excel

Comment: Because you'll be distributing this VBA, I would try to make the VBA as small and simple as possible. A good way to do it, would be to.. have the VBA download a CSV from a web interface =p. You should also try to convince your boss that doing this in excel is terrible solution.

Comment: @user606723 is there any smart way at all to do this with excel?

Comment: The article you linked to has to do with **database** security, not **connection** security. It looks like you are talking about SSL or some type of connection encryption.

Comment: @JP. oh oh yes. that is a good point. i need connection security

Comment: What method are you currently using to push and pull data?

Comment: @JP.  i have no method right now. i am just beginning. my boss wants me to use excel to pull data

Comment: @JCooper do you recommend i use a web app instead? how is that more secure?

Comment: @JCooper is a web app more secure because instead of connecting to the DB, i actually connect to the WEB APP that connects to the datbase?

Comment: So you need to pull your data from a webservice not a database?

Comment: @JCooper it is a database, but maybe i should make it into a web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allowing users direct connections to your database is tricky.  First off, you expose yourself to attack from without, as user accounts are compromised more frequently than well-isolated admin and service accounts.  Having said that, the user account does need to be compromised to allow an attacker into the system, and you have good granularity of control built into SQL Server if every user has their own credentials.

Using the Excel-native interfaces isn't that different from doing it via VBA or VSTA, which is how most developers did it for the last decade or so.  Those methods are about as secure as your network.  I believe the Excel-native functionality works without extraneous references, as well, which is particularly nice for maintenance purposes.  The main difference seems to be in the ability to do arbitrary queries.  For security and data integrity purposes, this is probably for the best.

Running a stored procedure is probably not a good idea, as you can get into massive support requirements if your users start needing(wanting) tweaks frequently.  Can you make do with a view?  Excel's inbuilt filtering and sorting abilities are pretty powerful.  That would be my first approach.

There are several approaches depending on your needs:

1 - modify your schema to allow the database to tie data to individual users

2 - move the access code into a VBA macro associated to the workbook.  This is not recommended, but it will allow you to use ADO directly. Be SURE you have a solid security configuration on the database side if you do this, as an attacker who gains access to a user's account will be able to do anything that user can do.

To go the VBA route, in the VBA environment Tools->References to find the latest Microsoft ADO version.  The VBA code looks something like this:

```
Dim Connection as ADODB.Connection
Set Connection = new ADODB.Connection
Connection.Open"Provider=SQLNCLI;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=yes;"
Dim command As ADODB.command
command.CommandText = "exec sp_something"
Dim Parameters(2) As ADODB.Parameter

Set Parameters(1) = New ADODB.Parameter
Parameters(1).Name = "field_name"
Parameters(1).Type = adVarChar
Parameters(1).Size = 50

Set Parameters(2) = New ADODB.Parameter
Parameters(2).Name = "field_name_2"
Parameters(2).Type = adVarChar
Parameters(2).Size = 50

Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(Parameters) To UBound(Parameters)
    command.Parameters.Append Parameters(i)
Next i

Dim Records As ADODB.Recordset
Set Records = command.Execute
```

Tie that macro to your button, set up your values via the sheet or an input box, and fire away.  But I'll repeat my warning: Going this way leads to massive support requirements.  If people want to extract custom data, then they get very particular about it.

Comment: thank you so much fo ryour response. im not sure if i can do views because the users will need to supply parameters. is this still possible with a view? are you suggesting that it is OK to do this with windows authenticaiton?

Comment: It would be secure in the sense that your connections will not be interceptable.  As long as you are careful about the permissions you grant them (ie read only on a limited number of DB objects), it will also be secure from the standpoint of preserving data integrity.  It is still more subject to attack in most cases than a well-built web architecture, but as long as your users are reasonably careful they should not be compromised, and even if they are you are only subject to data theft, rather than data loss.

Comment: Views allow you to hardcode parameters, but no, you will not be able to supply parameters using this configuration.  That is why I mentioned the filtering and sorting built into Excel - educated users are able to use these basic tools to pull out the data they need.

Comment: the problem is there are many gigs of data, so we cant just dump the whole thing for the user

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the article you linked, I'd rather use VBA script with reference to the ADO library and a normal connection string with a technical SQL user.

Since the password would be in the connection string in this case, this technical user should have no other rights than executing your stored procedures.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: thanks so much for your response. so is excel an OK tool to do this?

Comment: You know, in an ideal world, Excel does not exist. I'm not saying it's OK but I've done things even worse. Company department with no proper tools, but the need is there to measure KPIs of key processes. Let' say simply that it works. Like you can make your dinner with a swiss army knife. It's no good but it works.